# Javascript - change outside variable inside a function after passing it as an argument

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have a simple function and I want it to be executed only once. Therefore I created `status.example_1` and `status.example_2`. When the function is executed status should change from `false` to `true`, but it doesn't work. It is passed to `myFunction` as an argument `e2` and this is the cause of the problem.

Is there any way to make it work? What am I missing here?

```js
(function(){
    
    var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn-1'),
        btn2 = document.getElementById('btn-2'),
        status = {
            example_1:  false,
            example_2:  false,
        };
      
    function myFunction(e1,e2){
        if(e2 === false){
            console.log('Button: ' + e1);
            e2 = true;
        }
    }
    
    btn1.addEventListener('click',function(){
        myFunction(1,status.example_1);
    });
    
    btn2.addEventListener('click',function(){
        myFunction(2,status.example_2);
    });
    
})();
```

```html
<button id="btn-1">Click-1</button>
<button id="btn-2">Click-2</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your function should receive the entire object to be able to modify it, as you are passing only 1 property, it is like a new variable, instead:

```
function myFunction(e1,e2){
    if(e2 === false){
        console.log('Button: ' + e1);
        e2 = true;
    }
}
```

you can try

```
function myFunction(e1,status){
    if(status[`example_${e1}`] === false){
        console.log('Button: ' + e1);
        status[`example_${e1}`] = true;
    }
}
```

and

`myFunction(2,status);`